# DropShadowEffect Color binding not working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I'd like to bind one of the viewmodel's properties to the Color of a DropShadowEffect. I have tried like a thousand variations but none of them seemed to work.

The style:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}" x:Key="CentralImageStyle">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Effect">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0" 
                    Color="{Binding Path=DataContext.CurrentPlayer.Character, Converter={StaticResource CharacterColorConverter},
                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" 
                    Opacity="1" BlurRadius="50"/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

The Control:

```
<Image Source="{Binding CurrentPlayer.BackImageSource}"
       Style="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=CentralImageStyle}">
```

and the converter:

```
switch ((string)value)
{
    case "char1":
        return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.WhiteSmoke);
    case "char2":
        return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
    default:
        return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
}
```

My problem is that the color of the DropShadowEffect is black. That kinda means that the converter isn't used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're binding to the Color property, but the converter is returning Brushes. Remove the SolidColorBrush's from the converter and just return Colors.WhiteSmoke, Colors.Red, etc...